# Корректно ли писать "сказал" вместо "спросил" в диалогах?

Tags: прямая-речь

— Что ты думаешь по этому поводу? — **спросил** Андрей.

— Что ты думаешь по этому поводу? — **сказал** Андрей.

Answer (score 1):

**Принципиально такое допустимо. Но в вашем случае выглядит как ошибка.**

Это, мне кажется, вопрос языкового слуха, поэтому трудно сформулировать прямо-таки правила. Ясно, что риторические вопросы могут снабжаться ремаркой "сказал" или "воскликнул", потому что они не совсем вопросы. Так же и вопросы, не требующие ответа:

> ― Ты подумай, что ты говоришь? ― сказал Ёжик. *[Сергей Козлов. Как Ёжик с Медвежонком спасли Волка]*
>
> ― Эй, зачем ты ругаешься? ― сказал он, убирая пистолет в карман. *[Андрей Геласимов. Ты можешь]*
>
> ― Что может быть проще?! ― сказал Трюмо. ― Архивы находятся в Грассе. *[Довлатов. Иная жизнь]*

Может сопровождаться ремаркой "сказал" вопрос, в котором по факту содержится утверждение:

> ― Значит, не возьмёте меня на работу? ― сказала я директрисе. *[Андрей Геласимов. Жанна]*

Мне кажется, что если есть ремарка "спросил", то следующей репликой должен быть ответ или фраза, содержащая комментарий типа "ответа не последовало".